# How can I make Bootstrap div full width? (based on screen)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the code I wrote using Bootstrap:

```
 <div class='container-fluid' >
    <div style='background-color:#24242a;height:20vh;margin-top:10%;left:0;margin-left:0%;'>
        <div class="row" style='padding-top:20px;width:100%;' >
            <center><h1 style='font-weight: 400;letter-spacing: 0.05em;color:#E4D5D5;'>CINE SUNTEM <span style='font-weight:bold;'>NOI?</span></h1></center>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            1
          </div>


          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            2
          </div>


          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            3
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
  </div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

But the div is only 80% the width of the screen and centered. How can I make it 100% width? I will appreciate all answers.

Comment: A fiddle or pen with a demo would be nice for us to debug your code.

Comment: @IsabelInc I use bootstrap and that would mean to link all the style sheets etc. and I use a lot of them.

Comment: @V.Mike Codepen and JSFiddle allow you to include Bootstrap easily. Please take a look at these tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class container-fluid is not supposed to be full width. If you want to e.g. add a background color that stretches to 100% width of the window I suggest you make a wrapper div outside of the container-fluid:

```
<div style="width:100%; height: 600px; background-color: red;">
<div class="container-fluid">...</div>
</div>
```

The container-fluid class is just a fluid container as an addition to the normal container class from Bootstrap. I have used this many times and it should work! Try the code above to check it out.

**EDIT**

The OP used the code above to introduce a full-width container with Bootstrap. He also had the additional problem of having a parent div, which already had the container class. Beware of this as the parent can also additionally limit the ability to introduce full-width window divs.

Comment: The height worked but the width didn't. I forgot to mention that I also have a main <div class='container'> that contains all the content on my page.

Comment: @V.Mike You should remove the parent div container if you want this to work :) You can always make the full-width wrapper divs below one another and use div containers inside as shown in my example in order to preserve the bootstrap layout

Comment: @V.Mike yes I know :) I saw your code. You have to interrupt your parent div container by closing it. Then you add my code and then you can open another div container below to continue with the layout

Comment: Deleteing the div solved my problem. Edit your answer saying this and I will ACCEPT it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @V.Mike I am glad I could help. Should I edit my answer about your parent div container?